# Images Overlapped by a Div?

Tags: css

I have a JS fiddle here.  It's been a while since I've worked in CSS and HTML...

http://jsfiddle.net/Peege151/4Au3c/
 Here is the HTML

```
 <body>
    <div id="logo" style="font-family: AlexBrush-Regular;font-size:500%">
        XYZ
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="navbar">
            Item Item Item
        </div>

        <div id="main">
                <div id="fb">

                </div>
              <div id="tweet">

                </div>
            <img src="/emmybg.jpg" alt=""style ="height:600px">


        </div>

    </div>
     </body>
```

and this is my css

```
   body {
    background-color:#666666;
    text-align: center`
}
#content{
    width: 75%;
    background-color:#666666;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
#navbar{
    height:30px;
    width:100.4%;
    background-color:#000000;  
    color: #ffffff
}
@font-face {font-family: AlexBrush-Regular; src: url('AlexBrush-Regular.ttf');} 
logo {
    font-family: AlexBrush-Regular;
    text-align:center;
}
#tweet {
    float:right;
    width:17%;
    height:600px;
    border:solid red;
}
#fb {
    float:left;
    width:17%;
    height:600px;
    border:solid red;
}
#main {
    height:600px; 
    width:100%; 
    border: solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#main .img{
    float:left;
        height:500px;
        border: solid black;

}
#footer{
    height:30px;
    background-color:#000000;  
    color: #ffffff
}
```

Notice in the JSFiddle - As the page resizes, those red content boxes stay the same size.
In the middle of those, I have an image...
When the page is resized, the image pops on another line.  I would like to force the image to stay in-line..."

If possible though, I would like the image to "disappear" under the red content boxes, so the aspect ratio isn't changed.  If they go beyond the far edges of the red boxes, I will hide overflow there.

Is that possible?
Hopefully I have phrased my question clearly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you simply set the image as a background?

Comment: Wow. I will try... Why didn't I think of that XD

Comment: Let me know if it works, and/or accept as an answer if it does. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the image as a background, rather than an `<img>` tag?

I added these to the #content styles

```
background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/600); /* I used a placekitten since I can't see your example image*/
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
```

Note that `background-position:center center;` ensures the sides get cut off if the image is too big, but the image is always central.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Au3c/2/

Comment: Thank You! I loved the kitten haha...I tried that... That's kind of an improvement, but I'm working with an image that doesn't have a square aspect ratio. I'd like to have it resize the whole image together... my boxes should get smaller on the height aspect once I squish the page down...  Not sure how do that. The image size is huge..4288 × 2848. My brain is becoming fried

Comment: Once resized enough, the image has gray space underneath, because it's the image is being shrunk on the Y but not on the X...ugh I should be able to figure this out...

Comment: IE9+ and all sensible browsers support background resize, would this help? http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/